# Using methods created from an interface?

Tags: java, interface, game-engine

How do i use an interface method? for example, i'm making a game engine. i want to have a JFrame blueprint type of idea, so i have a class called `HFrame`. when an object of HFrame is made, it will run through all of the settings and stuff through the constructor. When i call `objectOfHFrame.display()`, how do i get the `display`, which is located inside of the HFrame class, to call `draw()`, which will be a type of `paint(Graphics)` method created by a interface class called `Frame`?

I'm awful at wording these questions, please feel free to ask for clarification!

thanks :)

EDIT:
Sorry about the confusion, i did say i suck at this kind of thing....
lets use the Thread example, implementing Runnable to create the run() method. Runnable creates the run() method in a class. a Thread object then takes a class that implements runnable, and calls run(). 1) how does the thread object know that the class implemented runnable, and 2) is there a way for a class like Thread to call a method like Run without passing a class to that Thread object?

EDIT 2:
sorry again, i suck -_-
ok, on that #2....
When making a thread object, you call `Thread t = new Thread(objectOfClassImplementingRunnable);`. My question is this: is it possible to, lets say make an object of a class, called HFrame, that calls a method named `draw()`, JUST like the Thread does but with `run()`, without passing the `objectOfClassImplementingAnotherInterface`? and if not, how do you get the HFrame class to KNOW if the object passed implements FRAME?

Comment: What is your issue?  What have you tried?

Comment: No idea what this question is asking.

Comment: An interface is a blueprint of your methods for classes to implement, you wouldn't necessarily be calling your interface's methods, but, rather your class that implements the interface must have all the methods defined in the interface.

Comment: 1) cause it has Runnable Type, java is strong typed language. 2) Don't get your question

Comment: what do you mean "runnable type", how does one do this? and then look at the edit #2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your use of terminology is.. interesting, sounds Greek to me, but I'll try to guess what your meant.

I assume you created a class `HFrame` which extends `JFrame`. You added a method `display()` to your `HFrame`. (You probably don't need to do that, and instead just use the existing method `objectOfHFrame.setVisible(true);`

When a frame is made visible, it will start the chain of events that will eventually result in the frame's (and all its children's) `paint(Graphics g)` method to be called. You don't need to worry about that, it's automatic.

I did not understand what interfaces have to do with that; the above are classes, not interfaces.

If I translated your language to Java incorrectly, please feel free to correct me. I highly recommend to read some 101 type of tutorial before plunging into coding.

Edit: ah, OK, based on your edit, I got it all wrong. Hold on... need more translation first.

> lets use the Thread example, implementing Runnable to create the run() method

This may sound like nit picking, but implementing an interface does not create any methods; it just forces the compiler to fail if the methods are absent. (Though an IDE may actually create a method for you if you ask nicely :-)

> 1) how does the thread object know that the class implemented runnable

That's the beauty of a strongly typed language. Giving Thread a class to run that does not implement Runnable will result in a compilation error. The compiler is strong enough to catch that. If it was not, Java also has this syntax: `if (object instanceof Runnable){...}`

> 2) is there a way for a class like Thread to call a method like Run without passing a class to that Thread object?

You mean, can a thread be started without specifying a Runnable object which to start? No. How would it know which runnable to start, without pointing to it? (BTW, a Thread, last I remember, implements Runnable, too, so theoretically one could subclass a Thread and then have it run itself, though that IMHO is bad design).

Edit 2. OK, my brain just melted. You may want to post some pseudocode, or look up Decorator pattern.

Comment: Haha i see.... well it was pretty close. i've actually gotten pretty good with programming and stuff, but my... question asking skills are something to be desired -_- display() is there for other reasons, but what i want is for the HFrame class to be completely customizable, besides the frame border itself. so what i was thinking is making the HFrame.display(), among other things, to call the draw() method previously mentioned, so taht anyone who uses the engine can change what is painted. Clearer? :D

Comment: Ah, I see, you are trying to implement the Decorator pattern... sort of. (except Decorator uses composition (which is generally superior), not inheritance, and what you are trying to do can already be accomplished by users overriding `paint()` or `update()` or a horde of other methods. But then, I don't know your design, maybe there is a need for a different plug.

Comment: well i just kinda got up one day and desided to make a game engine, usable for anyone, but more specifically for a game that i'm creating. so i wasnt really sure how to go about it tbh, so i started here, with interfaces and such

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept/upvote, I am new here and rather need that. BTW, the terms 'type' and 'class' in Java are roughly synonymous (I am only allowed to comment to my own answer at this point, but this pertains to the comments to your question)